# Diconnected mode in Source Safe

Tags: c#, vb.net, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I'm working on an application which has Source Safe as it's source control.

Today the sourceSafe(SS) machince has problems and our tech people are fixing the machine.

In this Scenario I can only work on the project(visual Studio 2003 C#) in an offline mode.

Question is what do you think about this? is this safe? I mean if the SS gets back online and I have already made changes to somefiles, does the merge goes smoothly or I should wait for SS machine to come up before chaging any code?

I would also like to know your opintion what happens in the scenario above with any other Version-cnotrol Software (SVN,CVS, ...) If you have experience for similar scenario with any software, your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I know you probably get bored of hearing this, but my many-years-of-personal-experience with VSS tells me one thing very loud and clear: *stop using VSS* (by which I mean, transition to something else instead; *anything* else).

Comment: I know. I was using SVN in my previous company. But in my current company I have to work with dinasaur software. SS, .Net 2003, Framework 1.1. I have no choice here.

Comment: So Marc, what is the version control software of your choice?

Comment: I like hg, but some people swear by git; others like svn. There are plenty to choose from. My personal choice is probably not very important in real terms. However: VSS is *not* comparable to most (if any) of these.

Comment: It should be noted that your use of .NET 2003 / 1.1 does not dictate your options here. You don't have to use the IDE support of the tools; just treat it as a flat file-system.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Do you know if any of above software will work smoothly in my case? That is I work offline for a while and then they take changes smoothly?

Comment: pretty much **every** other tool on the market is designed to work that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the only one who works on the files? If so, it should be fine. You can make changes offline and check them into VSS DB when it's online. If you have multiple people working on the same files, there would be problem when you try to check in & merge changes from different members.

Comment: That's also what I was guessing.